# How are atlases and other large books made in LaTeX?

Tags: typography, book-design, workflow

I was wondering how large books such as atlases or encyclopedias were made in LaTeX?

For example, how does one setup their document or design the layout for such a big book? Is it the same process as writing a standard book or are there special things one has to look out for? I am not looking to make one myself, I was just curious.

Comment: *> Atlas* I can't imagine there's a single cartographer out there crazy or masochistic enough to seriously try that. TeX and friends are great tools for a lot of applications, but there's applications they simply were not made for, and this is certainly one of them...
*> Encyclopedias* entirely different story. Nothing too special about it; it's being done a lot AFAIK.

Comment: [Typesetting a Dictionary with LaTeX](http://www.mengensatz.de/blog/?p=69)

Comment: [This example](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58218/8528) is truly impressive, and quite beautiful, I think.